# How to change action bar navigation onClick listener from fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a toolbar in activity with a fragment container

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tlUsersActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />
```

I run these lines to control the backpressed button

```
    setSupportActionBar(binding?.tlUsersActivity)
    if (supportActionBar != null) {
        when (intent.getStringExtra(MainActivityAdmin.FRAGMENT_TYPE)) {
            "View Users" -> {
                supportActionBar?.title = viewUsersText
}

    "Edit Users" -> {
        supportActionBar?.title = editUsersText
    }
}
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        binding?.tlUsersActivity?.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
```

I want to change this action from inside the fragment, I want to replace it with a function that replaces fragments.
I've tried this but it didn't work

```
    val actionBar = view?.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.tlUsersActivity)
    actionBar?.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        replaceFragment(FragmentEditUsers())
    }
```

Comment: You want to interact with the activity toolbar from the fragment right?

Comment: yes, I want to change the navigation button listener

Comment: Ok. In this case, instead of interacting directly with the toolbar inside the fragment, you need to interact with the activity. You can do it with the help of callbacks. But fragments now have FragmentResultListener which can help make the activity/fragment interaction easier. Or just add a shared view model for the activity and fragment, but it's not a good practice) If you want I can answer with a code snippet.

Comment: Yes please, I would like the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly working with Activity from the fragment is not a good practice, it will become a nest of bugs in the future))
The first option is `SharedViewModel` which you can share between your activity and fragment. But maybe you don't want it if you have simple functionality and you don't want to involve `ViewModel` here.
The second option, which usually was used before `Fragment Result API` and `SharedViewModel` were callbacks.
The third one which I prefer and it's way cleaner is `Fragment Result API`.
You can find more information here - [FragmentResultAPI & SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate).
Using it you can communicate between activity-to-fragment, vice-versa, and fragment-to-fragment.

You need a Gradle dependency to use it:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"
```

In the activity, you have to set a `FragmentResultListener`. It takes as a parameter the request key, lifecycle, and `FragmentResultListener` interface which is a SAM interface (has only 1 function). You can deep-dive here if you want.

```
const val REQUEST_KEY = "101"
const val BUNDLE_KEY = "B101"

// Activity code
supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(REQUEST_KEY, this) { requestKey, bundle ->
        if (requestKey == REQUEST_KEY) {
            // Here you can call the functions you desire
            Toast.makeText(this, bundle.getString(BUNDLE_KEY), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Now let's have a look at the fragment side. I have one button and after clicking I trigger the result listener in the activity:

```
// Fragment code
val btnTriggerActivity = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_trigger_activity)
btnTriggerActivity.setOnClickListener {
    // This code will trigger the function in activity.
    // The activity will show the toast
    setFragmentResult(REQUEST_KEY, bundleOf(
        BUNDLE_KEY to "Hello from the other side :)"
    ))
}
```

That's it. Here's also an image from the developer's page which shows the communication of fragment-to-fragment using `FragmentResultApi`.

[image]